# Upload file to non input field using behat

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, behat

Recently our app got updated to AngularJS and the fields got changed. So before we had a field to upload a file that was  field. But now the field changed to  type of field.

I used attachFileToField() solution provided by MinkContext but it did not work and got this error.

> Impossible to attach a file on the element with XPath "(//html//file-upload)[1]" as it is not a file input (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

Is there a way to attach the file to the new field that is not an input field with type of file?

HTML snippet for the specific field:

`<file-upload model="save_obj.resume[index].uploaded_file" parent="save_obj" parent-object="save_obj" parent-object-id="student.student_id" file-field-name="resume" static="true" template-url="resume-upload.html" flex="" class="ng-isolate-scope flex">`

Searched for a solution for whole day but no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look for any related input, maybe there is hidden. Can you share the html snippet of the section?

Comment: @lauda I've checked through out the html and there are no input tag related to file upload.

Comment: @lauda I've updated the question with the snippet of the field.

Comment: This doesn't help much, seems to be only one element and not the entire section of the upload. Maybe the input stays hidden or is created when you click on a button. Also an online demo of this would help. Try it manually and check the changes in the page.